# Group items (containing differing structures) of a multidimensional array and sum column values per group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have the following input:

```
$data = [
    [
        'date' => '2014-01-01',
        'sales' => 1,
        'price' => ['usd' => 1, 'eur' => 100],
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2014-01-05',
        'sales' => 1,
        'price' => ['usd' => 1, 'eur' => 100, 'gbp' => 500]
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2016-03-27',
        'sales' => 5,
        'age' => 50
    ],
    [
        'date' => '2016-03-28',
        'sales' => 10
    ]
];
```

I need to sum the `sales` column data and the child elements of the optionally occurring `price` column per group to produce the following result:

```
$final = array(
    'March 2016' => array(
        'sales' => 15
    ),
    'January 2014' => array(
        'sales' => 2,
        'price' => array(
            'usd' => 2,
            'eur' => 200,
            'gbp' => 500
        )
    )
);
```

What I've done so far:

```
$monthlyData = array();
        
foreach ($dailyData as $day)
{
    $key = date('M y', strtotime($day['date']));

    if (!isset($monthlyData[$key]))
    {
        $monthlyData[$key] = $day;
        continue;
    }

    foreach ($day as $metric => $value)
    {
        if(!empty($value)) 
        {
            $monthlyData[$key][$metric] += $value;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that we can use good ol' `foreach` (with recursive calls) in order to get the right result, but I'm looking for some more elegant solution.

Comment: Is the data from a MySQL table? If so, may be more elegant to sum in the query itself.

Comment: No, it's response from API. :-(

Comment: is `'price' => array(` of your first element a `price` or a `prices`?

Comment: The sample structure in example is different from that in your code. Do you want keys in `March 2016` format or `March 03 Format`? Do you want `date` subkey or not?

Comment: @fusion3k, good catch. Some fields will be excluded, e.g. `date` - but I will do this at later stage. Also, I just need them in the following format: `March 2016`, `April 2016`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really just need one more condition and loop for this specific example.

```
foreach ($day as $metric => $value)
{
    /* Added Condition */
    if(is_array($value))
    {
        foreach($value as $nestedMetric => $nestedValue) {
            $monthlyData[$key][$metric][$nestedMetric] += $nestedValue;
        }
    }
    elseif(!empty($value)) 
    {
        $monthlyData[$key][$metric] += $value;
    }
}
```

[Output](https://3v4l.org/0BM6D):

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Warning: Undefined array key "gbp"

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered
array (
  'Jan 14' => 
  array (
    'date' => 4028,
    'sales' => 2,
    'price' => 
    array (
      'usd' => 2,
      'eur' => 200,
      'gbp' => 500,
    ),
  ),
  'Mar 16' => 
  array (
    'date' => 4032,
    'sales' => 15,
    'age' => 50,
  ),
)
```

However, I'd probably do it differently by handling the calculation based on the metric, not just treating every metric dynamically.

Comment: The user who asked the question does not want to use 'foreach'.

Comment: @FaiyazAlam, yeah, I overlooked the last line.  The user will most likely have to use another loop at some point, we'll see if any other answers pop up.  This is pretty broad if the OP is looking for us to rewrite his code.

Answer (score 0):

While iterating over the variably-populated items, reformat the date and remove the day-portion. Then push the sales data into its designated group in the result array; if re-encountering the group, add the current value to the stored value.

If the `price` element has children, iterate over them and push them (or add them) to their designated element in the same fashion as described earlier.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QhqkY))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($data as $set) {
    $group = (new DateTime($set['date']))->format('M Y');
    $result[$group]['sales'] = ($result[$group]['sales'] ?? 0) + $set['sales'];
    foreach ($set['price'] ?? [] as $currency => $amount) {
        $result[$group]['price'][$currency] = ($result[$group]['price'][$currency] ?? 0) + $amount;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```